# Ensure collision detection triggers only once per collision

Tags: c++, visual-c++, collision-detection, cocos2d-x, marmalade

I am trying collision detection without using Box2d,
so i used a inbuilt function CCRectIntersectsRect()
using this function when i decrement the count it gets reduced to negative values in a single collision. (when the ball touches hero and when the ball crosses hero.)

All i want is to schedule it in someway so that the count-- gets called once only.

For complete source code [how to use box2d for collision detection in cocos2d-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043232/how-to-use-box2d-for-collision-detection-in-cocos2d-x/9043382#9043382)

```
CCRect bom= ball->boundingBox();
CCRect gon= hero->boundingBox();

if(CCRect::CCRectIntersectsRect(bom,gon))
{
    count--;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a persistent bool variable called `colliding`, and use it like this:

```
if(CCRect::CCRectIntersectsRect(bom,gon))
{
    if (!colliding)
        count--;
    colliding = true;
}
else
    colliding = false;
```

Here's the fix for the code you provided in the comments below:

```
CCRect bom= roll->boundingBox();
CCRect gon= hero->boundingBox();
static bool colliding=false;
if(CCRect::CCRectIntersectsRect(bom,gon))
{
    if (!colliding)
    {
        intersection();
        colliding = true;
    }
}
else
    colliding = false;
```

Comment: @jeet.mg: You probably put it in the wrong place.  You didn't make it local to the function did you? (that was a rhetorical question, because I'm almost certain that you did) It needs to be in a place where its value will persist between function calls.

Comment: i tried to declare it in *.h but, it gave an error of unresolved external. and so i did that intentionally.

Comment: @jeet.mg: Is this a member function?  Then put the variable as a member of the class.  Otherwise, you can make it a static local variable.  I saw your comment that you apparently deleted, and you did have it as a static.  However, your code was wrong, it was not doing the same thing as my code.  You had the else in the wrong place.  Let me see that code again, and I'll show you how to fix it.

Comment: @jeet.mg: Yep, it's like I said.  The `else` is in the wrong place.  I'll put the fixed version in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

initialize count with 1
    if(CCRect::CCRectIntersectsRect(bom,gon) && count > 0)
    {
        count--;
    }

Comment: count is life of hero (set to 3 initially) and goes on decreasing up to 0